# Trying to run dapp in metamask mobile browser

Tags: metamask, private-blockchain, dapps

I would like to run a dapp in metamask mobile browser, but got stuck in below things:

```
1. Unable to view the console errors(inspect element) in the application
2. How to visualise page load values or functions? ( For eg: USERID display while loading the corresponding page)
```

Mobile OS: Android Version

It's working fine in Web browser(Google Chrome) using metamask extension.

Help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

For 1) I suggest you **do not** use any wallet built-in browsers. Not only being hard to debug, these embedded WebViews have other bugs and issues making the normal web browser APIs to fail.

Instead, use the stock Android Chrome that has [remote debugging capabilities](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/remote-debugging/). Then use WalletConnect for any wallet actions in a mobile browser.

For 2) looks like this is a generic web programming question and not suitable for this forum.

Answer (score 0):

For (2) You can use `alert` function in your javascript code instead of `console.log` to view values or trace the program on phone browsers.